# How do I fix make Tweepy re-choose randomly from random users if there's a duplicate tweet?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to get the last tweet from random users each time and update the status of my account with that:

```
import tweepy
import tweepy as tp
import time
import sys
import random


consumer_key = 'X'
consumer_secret = 'X'
access_token = 'X'
access_secret = 'X'


auth = tp.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
api = tp.API(auth)

count = 0
while (count < 1):
    my_twitter_id = ("placeholder1", "placeholder2", "placeholder3", "placeholder4", "placeholder5", "placeholder6")
    def user_tweet(twitter):
        statuses = api.user_timeline(screen_name=twitter)
        return statuses[0].text

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        latest_tweet = user_tweet(random.choice(my_twitter_id))
        api.update_status(latest_tweet)
        time.sleep(10)
```

However after 2 or 3 successful tweets, it gives the error 187, status is a duplicate which to my understanding, it's trying to get a tweet it already tweeted before. How do I make it re-choose randomly from one of the users (placeholders) if there's a duplicate tweet?

Also another thing, how do I make it exclude retweets and replies?